добавить информацию через форму в бд
не добавляется информация через форму, после ввода в инпут нажимаю на кнопку и ничего не происходит, в базе информация не появляется
<form method="post" action="add_track.php" class="block"></form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите название трека" class="name" name="name">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите исполнителя трека" class="ispol" name="ispol">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Введите ссылку на изображение трека" class="link" name="link">
        <button type="submit" class="add"></button>
    </form>



<?php
    require_once 'connect.php';


    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $ispol = $_POST['ispol'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];

    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `track` (`name`, `performer`, `img`) 
    VALUES ('$name', '$ispol', '$link')");

    header('Location: /')
    
?>


Возможный дубликат вопроса: Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?

Убедитесь, что данные уходят с фронта. Далее проверьте, что принимает РНР скрипт. Убедитесь, что SQL запрос сформирован правильно(в mysql кавычки играют роль). Далее надо проверить что отправка запроса в mysql осуществляется без ошибок и что ответ от mysql приходит правильный(нет ошибок). Т.е. если итоговый результат вас не устраивает(не работает), на проверять всю цепочку вызова и искать, где ломается

Если "запрос не работает", это может быть вызвано следующими причинами:

До выполнения запроса дело вообще не дошло, из-за некорректной логики в коде программы. Чтобы это проверить, надо добавить временный отладочный вывод (или использовать пошаговую отладку в IDE)
При выполнении запроса произошла ошибка. Необходимо настроить РНР так, чтобы он сообщал обо всех ошибках, в том числе при работе с БД. См. рекомендации в этом ответе.

В случае, если запрос был выполнен, и при этом без ошибок, но при этом не сделал то что нужно, причины могут быть следующие:

Не было найдено совпадение в условии WHERE. Надо проверять входящие данные, и данные, которые лежат в БД.
Если запрос на изменение данных, то иногда бывает, что результат запроса проверяют не в той базе данных. Например, phpmyadmin работает с БД, которая настроена на порт 8889, а РНР работает с БД на порту 3306. Надо убедиться, что результат запроса проверяется в той же самой БД.
Как вариант, изменения происходят в рамках открытой транзакции, которой потом не делают commit. Надо убедиться, что транзакция не стартует или что она подтверждается.

